# What exactly is manna?

Tags: history, tradition, exodus, jews, diet

In the Bible account of Exodus, God gives the Jews a type of bread called "Manna".

What exactly is manna? What is in it? Do Jews or Christians still eat it today? If so, do they eat it at certain times? What does it taste like?

I wanted to be a chef many years ago, but that didn't pan out, so to speak. Cooking food has always been a passion, as is learning. I want to find out more about this bread and try to recreate it if possible.

This is in reference to researching the historical diet of both the early Jews and Christians. The scope of that is much to wide to ask in total right now, so I will ask in parts, starting with manna.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, the word "manna" itself means "What is it?" so I'm not sure you're going to find a perfectly satisfactory answer to your question. :-)

In addition, it was created supernaturally by God, and He didn't share the recipe. :-)

Since it was a single miracle, and not something that people still eat today, no one really knows personally what it tastes like. However, the KJV states in Exodus 16:31, "It was like coriander seed, white; and the taste of it was like wafers made with honey."

I would not say that it was necessarily bread as we think of it, since Exodus 16:21 states that when the sun beat down in the afternoon, the manna melted.